# Is an .htaccess edit necessary when enabling Cloudflare SSL?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, https, cloudflare

I have recently changed 3-4 of my sites to Cloudflare SSL. After that, I went to General Settings on WordPress and changed URLs from HTTP to HTTPS.

And it redirects from HTTP to HTTPS without any issues. But I read many posts on various blogs and they all mention adding .htaccess redirect.

Is that really necessary? I'm confused as the redirect is already in place.

Answer (score 6):

It's really to do with *when* the redirect occurs.

WordPress/PHP naturally occurs *later* than `.htaccess`, so the HTTP request has already passed to PHP *before* the redirect occurs.

`.htaccess` is processed at the very start of the request, *before* it is passed to PHP.

However, if you are using CloudFlare then you should create a page rule to redirect HTTP to HTTPS to avoid unnecessary hits on your application server.

From a security point of view, you want to redirect to HTTPS as soon as possible.

Comment: So if I am using Cloudflare, what do you suggest, Should I add a redirect on CloudFlare or on htaccess or let it stay like this, from WordPress?

Comment: If you are using CloudFlare then you should create a page rule to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. This would be the preferred method. However, you still need to configure HTTPS in WordPress. And setting HTTP to HTTPS in `.htaccess` is a good fallback. However, note that how you configure `.htaccess` depends on your CloudFlare SSL type.

Answer (score 2):

## What `.htaccess` achieves

In this case, .htaccess can be used to redirect the requests from http to https once they hit the origin server, before they get to wordpress.

## Should I use this instead of cloudflare redirects

If you redirect on cloudflare instead of doing it with .htaccess then you can avoid having to hit the origin server which will speed up the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended that you update the site address for WordPress and let Cloudflare redirect HTTP to HTTPS with or without WWW. This way there's no need to use mod_rewrite which limits the server-side requests. See my blog entries below.

> SOURCE: [How to Enable SSL in the WordPress Dashboard](https://www.bybe.net/enable-ssl-wordpress-dashboard/)
>
> - Login to WordPress as an administrator
> - On the left hand side, hover over settings and then click General
> - Change these options:
>
>   - WordPress Address (URL) to `https://www.example.com`
>   - Site Address (URL) to `https://www.example.com`
>   - You will need to replace `example.com` with the actual name of your domain
> - Finally Click Save Changes
>
> Your WordPress setup should now update the internal permalinks of both
>   pages and assets. If you are getting mixed content warnings then you
>   need to dig deeper, possibly in the content or the design of your WP
>   theme.

---

> SOURCE: [Cloudflare Page Rule HTTPS 301 non-www to www](https://www.bybe.net/cloudflare-enforce-ssl-redirect-http-https/#cf-non-www-to-www)
>
> Login to Cloudflare and head over to the Page Rules section and
>   here you will need to add 3 new page rules.
>
> **Rule 1. Redirect HTTP NON-WWW to HTTPS WWW**
>
> - Click the Page Rules icon at the top of the screen
> - Click the Create Page Rule button
> - Enter `http://example.com/*` and obviously changing example domain with your own.
> - Under “Then the settings are:” click + Add a Setting
> - Click the dropdown list, find and click option “Forwarding URL”
> - Change the “Select Status Code” to 301 — Permanent Redirect
> - Add `https://www.example.com/$1` in the box below, but obviously changing example domain once again with your own domain name
> - Click Save and Deploy
>
> **Rule 2. Redirect HTTP WWW to HTTPS WWW**
>
> - Click the Page Rules icon at the top of the screen
> - Click the Create Page Rule button
> - Enter `http://www.example.com/*` and obviously changing example domain with your own.
> - Under “Then the settings are:” click + Add a Setting
> - Click the dropdown list, find and click option “Forwarding URL”
> - Change the “Select Status Code” to 301 — Permanent Redirect
> - Add `https://www.example.com/$1` in the box below, but obviously changing example domain once again with your own domain name
> - Click Save and Deploy
>
> **Rule 3. Redirect HTTPS NON-WWW to HTTPS WWW**
>
> - Click the Page Rules icon at the top of the screen
> - Click the Create Page Rule button
> - Enter `https://example.com/*` and obviously changing example domain with your own.
> - Under “Then the settings are:” click + Add a Setting
> - Click the dropdown list, find and click option “Forwarding URL”
> - Change the “Select Status Code” to 301 — Permanent Redirect
> - Add `https://www.example.com/$1` in the box below, but obviously changing example domain once again with your own domain name
> - Click Save and Deploy

Comment: Note if you are limited on page rules, you can also do a "redirect any non-WWW to WWW" and "redirect HTTP WWW to HTTPS WWW". It potentially includes an extra redirect for non-http non-www users, but fits in 2 rules.

Comment: Ya, you get 3 page rules for the free account. You can use Always use HTTPS as well but then you're adding an additional redirect.

Comment: If I just use Always use HTTPS and don't make this rules, would that be also fine? If I do that, should I still add redirect in htaccess file?

Comment: WordPress will naturally use a PHP redirect from NON-SSL to SSL if you update the site address within the WordPress settings page. Htaccess method redirects before PHP and Cloudflare redirects before both of those. Cloudflare is the best method because it reduces one request on your main server. If you use Cloudflare then you don't need to use htaccess, however, adding it won't harm it either because it'll not be used unless Cloudflare is disabled.